A company is dedicated to the manufacture of three kinds of lenses: A, B and C.
A company is dedicated to the manufacture of three kinds of lenses: A, B and C. The production procedure involves three operations: lens formation, where molten glass is transformed into raw lenses; inspection, a complex system where the properties of lenses are determined and classified according to their class; finishing, where an automatic procedure cuts and polishes the lenses. The industrial engineering department, after a thorough study of the production process, has established the following production standards:
https://i.sstatic.net/yrfXtMQ0.jpg
The owner of the company wants to know the number of each type of lenses that should be produced in one hour, so that the profit for the 8 hours of work per day is optimized.
a) Pose and solve the linear programming problem using the Simplex method.
b) By how much can the man-hours available in forming and finishing be reduced without changing the feasibility of the current mix?
c) What is the range of variation in the unitary utility of lens A where the unbeatability of the optimal mixture is maintained?
d) In which of the operations would you recommend hiring extra time?
e) If the manufacturing costs of lens A are reduced by 20%. How are the optimal solution and the objective affected?
But I have doubts about whether it is formulated correctly, because they ask me for the benefit per hour, so it should be 60 minutes, which is equivalent to one hour, or I take 480 minutes, which is equivalent to 8 hours. I want to clarify this so I can solve the simplex method
Los datos quedarían de esta forma:
Max$ \displaystyle Z= 25X_1  + 30X_2 + 45X_3$  función
Sujeto a:
$\displaystyle X_1  + 2X_2    + 3X_3   ≤ 480$ minutos
Que es el tiempo en que se forman.
$\displaystyle 3X_1  + 5X_2    + 6X_3   ≤ 480$ minutos
Que equivale a la inspección y
$\displaystyle 2X_1  +  3X_2    + 4X_3   ≤ 480$ minutos  el tiempo de acabado.
$ X1≥ 0     \\        X2≥ 0   \\                     X3≥ 0    $
Las restricciones de no negatividad.
From the proposed model I have obtained that I need to produce $160$ type A lenses to obtain the maximum profit of $4000$

This looks like a homework. You showed some work and that's good.
Concerning your question about 1h or 8 h, no one can answer, you'll have to ask to your teacher. Anyway the phrasing is quite unclear. For instance, does that mean that after 1 hour, everything is restarted anew? Since, this is in an "industrial" context, my guess would be "no". Another point, the 3 tasks seems to be ordered.
A hint would be to know if you have taking a course on Linear Programming or Integer Linear Programming. That makes some huge difference. And if it is your first course on it or not.

The simplest case is if we assume that the factory is in a steady state routine (and that it is fully automated so that there is no pause). Assuming that each of the 3 tasks (lens formation, inspection and finishing) are performed by 3 different machines (without transport delay), you are almost correct with your second formulation since the question is asking for the production for 1h. But the values in your constraints are really weird. I don't see how you come up with them given the table you have given (which I guessed how it is written since it is in Italian(?))

Hello, I have already corrected the exercise, you were absolutely right, from the proposed model I have obtained that I must produce 160 type A lenses in one hour to obtain the maximum profit of $4000, if each question is independent of the others, now my question arises in how to solve sections b, c, d, e that follow.?

The questions are not independent of each others For eample, for b), loo at the constraints with your optimal solution.

In each restriction it has been placed that the time must be less than or equal to 480, how can the man-hours available in forming and finishing be reduced without changing the viability of the current combination?

Did you compute the value of those man-hours? The constraint is that it is less or equal; it may be as well strictly less at optimality.

I haven't calculated the hours yet - men, how do I do it? Can the revised simplex method be used for this step? Please explain to me

What does $X_1+2X_2+3X_3$ represent in plain english? What is a man-hour? Or you can use the meaning of the slack variables in the simplex method also.

Ok, but what operation should I do with that inequality to calculate how much can the man-hours available in forming and finishing be reduced without changing the viability of the current combination? I don't understand, can I use the revised simplex method? If so, how do I apply it?
